# Dota 2 window does not show, Steam says it's "running"

Tags: games, steam, amd-graphics

Starting Dota 2 simply changes Steam's status to show it's running, but no window appears. After some Google-fu, I tried running it with the `-autoconfig` option, but there's no difference.

Team Fortress 2 runs perfectly, so it's not a Source Engine issue, I reckon.

About This Computer says my graphics is Gallium 0.4 on AMD KAVERI (DRM 2.43.0, LLVM 3.8.0). I've neither tried the closed-source driver, nor do I want to.

Comment: Have you checked the list of processes running to see if it is actually attempting to run?

Comment: @OwenHines, I haven't, but Steam does say it's already running if I try to start it again or any other game.

Comment: @OwenHines, I checked, and yes, `ps -aux` shows Dota 2 running.